# Why Laravel can't find my migration file?

Tags: php, laravel

After reading in [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/can-you-rename-migration-files-to-your-own-custom-format) that we can change our migration file conventions, I thought removing timestamp and setting a simple counter would be more maintainable.

```
001_first_table.php
002_second_table.php
003_third_table.php
```

But the problem is that now Laravel complaints that:

> Cannot declare class FirstTable, because the name is already in use

This error means **file name** is not matched with **class name**. This error doesn't happen when we prefix file names with timestamps, but happens if we change that scheme and replace the timestamp with ordinal series.

Why is it so? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this a fresh migration or you already had traces of an old migration in your database?

Comment: You likely have `class FirstTable extends Migration` as the Class Name for `002_second_table.php` or `003_third_table.php`; make sure those are unique.

Comment: @Jacobo it's a fresh migration.

Comment: @TimLewis, all files are unique. All class names are unique. And all file names match class names, except that class names don't start with that ordinal prefix.

Comment: Correct, they should be `class FirstTable extends Migration`, `class SecondTable extends Migration`, `class ThirdTable extends Migration`, without the `001`, `002` and `003`. Your error is suggesting that's the issue, and I believe you when you say they're structured like that, but that doesn't make much sense... Let me try to recreate.

Comment: The are indeed like that. `class FirstTable extends Migration`. To reproduce the error, simply change a migration's file name or class name so that they don't match. And see the error.

Comment: Confirmed; I have 2 files, `001_first_table.php` and `002_second_table.php`, with `class FirstTable extends Migration` and `class SecondTable extends Migration`, same error is thrown.

Comment: @TimLewis, I'll create an issue on GitHub. But it's weird. How do they handle those numbers in timestamps?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure; there's likely some logic being used to translate/relate the timestamp in the name to Class, but I don't see how/why. Good find!

Comment: @TimLewis, they don't have **issued** tab on their GitHub repository. I can't post an issue.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues You can probably post there?

Answer (score -3):

You should retstart from the beginning

php artisan migration:refresh

or If you did "unstandard changes" you should destroy you models and tables manually

model to delete in app\Models

table to delete : in the db

Comment: I also dropped the entire database and retried. Same error.

Comment: What did you try, delete your model manually?

Comment: I used `:fresh` switch with my migrate command. `php artisan migrate:fresh`. that diidn't work. Then I dropped the database entirely and created a new one. And ran migration as `php artisan migrate:install` and then `php artisan migrate` and again, the same error.

Comment: Ok, but your original error is your model that still exists ... model  is a php (class) file in app\Models

Comment: I don't have any model in Models directory yet. It's just a simple Laravel app and it only has migrations for now.

Comment: This is a migration and has nothing to do with Models

Comment: Read the comments to the question above (remember when I said it's best to wait for requests for clarification in our last discussion? This is why.)

Comment: You are rigth ... this time :-)